# Prevent Form Submission Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, form-submit, bootstrap-5

I need an answer to what I'm doing wrong in the below js. I have a bs5 form that the submission is not being prevented if fields are left blank or invalid. The html/css validation does work correctly when fields are invalid but submission is still allowed.

I am not well-versed at writing javascript (as you can tell) so any help is much appreciated!

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    let forms = document.querySelectorAll(".needs-validation");

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.from(forms).forEach(function (form) {
            form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
                 if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                        form.classList.add("was-validated");
                    }, false
            );
    });

    forms.forEach( function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      let thisForm = this;

      let action = thisForm.getAttribute('action');
      let recaptcha = thisForm.getAttribute('data-recaptcha-site-key');

      if( ! action ) {
        displayError(thisForm, 'The form action property is not set!')
        return;
      }
      thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.add('d-block');
      thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').classList.remove('d-block');
      thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.remove('d-block');

      let formData = new FormData( thisForm );

      if ( recaptcha ) {
        if(typeof grecaptcha !== "undefined" ) {
          grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            try {
              grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha, {action: 'php_email_form_submit'})
              .then(token => {
                formData.set('recaptcha-response', token);
                php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData);
              })
            } catch(error) {
              displayError(thisForm, error)
            }
          });
        } else {
          displayError(thisForm, 'The reCaptcha javascript API url is not loaded!')
        }
      } else {
        php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData);
      }
    });
  });

  function php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData) {
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
    })
    .then(response => {
      if( response.ok ) {
        return response.json()
      } else {
        throw new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText} ${response.url}`);
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
      if (data.type === 'success') {
        thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');
        thisForm.reset();
      } else {
        throw new Error(data ? data : 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      displayError(thisForm, error);
    });
  }

  function displayError(thisForm, error) {
    thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
    thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').innerHTML = error;
    thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').classList.add('d-block');
  }

})();
```

Comment: This isn't a Bootstrap issue. Bootstrap doesn't handle form submission or data. It's just a style library.

Comment: I should have been more clear. This is a Bootstrap theme and the theme includes js validation outside of what Bs offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your `event.stopPropagation()` command in the first declaration to happen, you must pass `true` instead of `false` to the `useCapture` argument of your `addEventListener` function.

Otherwise both will fire concurrently and none will take precedence over the other, and the only behaviour `stopPropagation` will achieve is stop the bubbling from the *submit* event, which won't help in what you're trying to achieve.

Edit: As stated in throught the comments, an alternative solution would be having both the validation and execution of the code happen under the same listener.

```js
// code before ...
forms.forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        if (!e.checkValidity()) {
            e.removeClass("was-validated");
            return; // interrupts the code to happen due to being invalid
        }
        
        e.addClass("was-validated");
        //...rest of the code
    })
});
// code after ...
```

**Related note**: `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` might be necessary in order to achieve the same behaviour in the browser Firefox

Comment: I changed it to true and it works as expected in Chrome but not Firefox :-(

Comment: Maybe my intrepretation of the documentation is incorrect, but overall I wouldn't suggest using 2 events to control this behaviour, I'd suggest using only one event listener to deal with your situation because right now the problem you're facing is how different browsers handle simultaneous event firings, and since what you're trying to do doesn't have anything related to this matter, I would suggest you just make everything happen on the same listener.

Comment: I think you are correct there. Any suggestions on how to integrate the two? I've tried doing exactly that but my syntax is wrong and I need the bottom portion of those functions to add the alert messages.

Comment: I updated my answer, I believe this change might suffice what you need. You can remove the `"was-validated"` class parts if they were just there because of your last implementation and they won't serve any purpose here

Comment: I appreciate your help! I also figured out the firefox issue... I added 'event.stopImmediatePropagation();' instead of 'event.stopPropagation();'.

Comment: I'm glad I was of help, don't worry, as I hope this situation might occur to someone else that is trying to solve a similar problem through the same way you did and might find this answer helpful to find out what's going on.